# gitignore not ignoring itself nor finding itself

Tags: git

I am trying to commit files in a directory

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
BigFile1.txt
BigFile2.txt
```

I accidentally tracked `BigFile1.txt` and `BigFile2.txt` when I first tried to push, but when I saw they were too large I stopped them from being tracked by git using `git rm --cached`. I made a `.gitignore` file

```
/BigFile1.txt
/BigFile2.txt
```

but when I try to commit now I get the following error

```
user:directory username$ git commit -m "asdf"
On branch master
Untracked files:
    .gitignore
    .gitignore~
```

nothing added to commit but untracked files present

When I try to remove `.gitignore` with `git rm --cached` I get

```
user:directory username$ git rm --cached .gitignore~
fatal: pathspec '.gitignore~' did not match any files
```

How do I just ignore `BigFile1.txt` and `BigFile2.txt` (they have different names in my directory so I can't use a wildcard for it) and commit and push to my remote without these complications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### An *untracked file* is one that is not in the index

You can't remove these files with `git rm` as they are not in the index.  As in the section title here, an untracked file is quite simply a file that is not in the index.

OK, but then what the heck *is* the index?

Git has three things that you work with as you make new commits:

- Your repository.  This has every commit you ever made (or picked up from anyone else), plus things like branch names to keep track of branch tips.  All this stuff is in a Git-only internal format.
- Your work-tree.  This is where you do your work, because it has the files in a non-Gitty form the rest of the computer can deal with.  It's also where you keep files that you don't *want* to commit.
- The *index*.  This thing has multiple roles, but the one we care about here is simple: it's where you build the *next commit* you will make.  The index has several other names: it's also called the *staging area*, and sometimes the *cache*.

The index starts off matching your current commit.  That is, for every file that's in the commit, Git copies that file to the index,<sup>1</sup> and then from the index to the work-tree.  Now you can work on it.

Once you are done working on it, you `git add` the file.  This tells Git: "copy the file from the work-tree into the index."  That replaces the previous version of the file in the index, so now the file is ready to go into the next commit.

That's almost all there is to it.  Of course, you might add a file you don't want, so you can `git rm` the file.  That *removes* the file—from *both* the index *and* the work-tree.  *Note that this does not touch any commits!*  It literally *can't*: a commit is permanent and unchanging.  Once made, no commit can *ever* change.  (The only thing you can do is throw it away entirely, making a new and improved one instead.)

Of course, if you don't want to remove a file from the work-tree, just from the index, you need to use `git rm --cached`.  But it still has to be in the index.  An untracked file is any file that is not in the index right now, so if it's untracked, `git rm --cached` cannot remove it from the index!

#### What gitignore does: it's not actually "ignore"

There are always some files that you want to keep around in your work-tree, but never want to add to your index.  Git keeps complaining: "Hey, I found this here work-tree file, and it's not in your index!  Maybe you ought to add it!"  We need to make Git *shut up* about these files, and that's a big chunk of what `.gitignore` does.

You can also add files en-masse to Git, with `git add .` or `git add -a` or similar; and in this case, we want to make sure Git doesn't *automatically* add these files.  That's most of the rest of what `.gitignore` does.

So `.gitignore` is really ".git-shut-up-about-these-untracked-files-and-do-not-auto-add-them-either".  That name is a bit too long, though, hence `.gitignore`.

You usually *do* want to commit `.gitignore` files.  If so, `git add` the `.gitignore` file (to copy it into the index) and eventually, `git commit` the result (to make the index into a new commit).  If you *don't* want this shut-Git-up thing to be permanently stored in commits, though, you probably should tell Git to shut up about these files outside a `.gitignore` (e.g., using `.git/info/exclude`: a file inside the repository directory that's not part of any commit).

#### You added the files *and committed them*

You mentioned:

> I accidentally tracked BigFile1.txt and BigFile2.txt when I first tried to push ...

This suggests that you `git add`-ed them *and then also `git commit`-ed the resulting index*.  This means those files are now *in a commit*.  Even if you `git rm --cached` the big files themselves now, that just takes them out of the index.  You have to "take them out" of a commit—and you and Git can't actually do that.  What you will need to do is to *copy* that commit to a new-and-improved version that does not have the big files.  Or, if that commit *only* adds the big files, ditch that commit entirely.  See any number of previous StackOverflow questions for how to do that.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, the index holds a *reference* to an internal Git *blob object*.  These internal blob objects are read-only: copying a totally-new version of a file into the index works by creating a new blob object, then referring to it.  Copying an existing version back into the index works by discovering that there's already a valid blob object holding the file content, and referring to it.  What this really boils down to is that copying a file into the index is "free" in that it doesn't take any disk space you weren't going to take anyway.  You can still think of it as a private copy in the index, even though it's really just a reference to a copy that Git already has, or will need in the future.

Comment: This helped me understand Git a bit more, thank you.