# Making git stop tracking generated files

Tags: git, version-control, repository, gitignore, atlassian-sourcetree

I have files that are generated by a build that got committed to a repository. Since the generated files cause errant merge conflicts, I have added them to the .gitignore.

After adding them to the gitignore, I deleted them from both my working copy as well as the the remote branch (4 people working on a single branch) directly and manually.

I ran the following commands as well:

```
git rm --cached assets/js/bundle.js
git rm --cached assets/sass/main.css
```

However, the files keep coming back any time I pull. I am working with people who are not knowledgeable in git and cannot control what they commit or how they merge.

I cannot pull until I manually delete the auto-generated files in my working copy since the two files keep coming back.

How can I make git stop tracking them forever? I don't understand why other dev's machines would keep bringing it back when I have already added it to the gitignore as well as completely removed it from the remote repository.

Comment: The problem is that *they* have not removed the files from *their* new commits. They must do so. It does not matter how many commits have or lack these files; what matters is what they put into *their* commits. A file that exists in some commit will be read into the index and will therefore be tracked, so that listing it in `.gitignore` has no effect. A file that does not exist in some commit will be read into the index as "does not exist" and removed from the index and not in a future commit, but they have to read that commit in—as in, `git checkout` that commit—for that to happen.

Comment: In other words, you're dependent on how other people use *their* Gits, and what they push to this shared repository. To avoid that dependency, set things up so that they cannot push directly to this repository: make them go through you first, and you can tell them "no" when they have files that they should not have committed. (Obviously this method has its own separate drawbacks.)

Comment: Can you configure git to refuse commits that contain the generated file? What does .gitignore do if not to tell the working copies to ignore files that are in the working copy that don't exist in the remote?

Comment: 1 *Can you configure git to refuse commits that contain the generated file?* Not exactly. If you control the server, you can—via a pre-receive or update hook—configure it to refuse a push request that adds a commit that fails any criteria you like, so you can inspect to see if some added commit(s) would contain forbidden file(s). That depends on server-side hooks, so you must have sufficient control of the server.

Comment: 2 *What does .gitignore do if not to tell the working copies to ignore files that are in the working copy that don't exist in the remote?* See https://stackoverflow.com/q/42333908/1256452

Comment: @RussellStrauss you can add .gitattribute file and define the folder as export-ignore. then clone the repo again, the files will not be exported, might still show on repository, since you don;t have any control on other people commiting stuff.

Comment: 1. Silly question: did you actually commit & push the removal of the files, and the `.gitignore` file, to the branch that everyone are working on? 2. After you pull, do those files appear as tracked? 3. If you run `git pull` twice in a row, does the second one fail because the files are there?

Comment: I modified and committed the gitignore first. Then I deleted the files and pushed. Then another team mate ran the build and git picked up their auto-generated files and added them back to the repository even though their new gitignore should prevent their source control from picking up new changes. Then I re-did the above steps, but this time removed it from the remote repository completely by deleting them from github directly. Pulling twice does not do anything differently from pulling once.

Comment: So if removing everything both locally and remotely and updating gitignore will not make other local copies ignore the files, I don't know what can. I believe deleting the repository completely (only an option for personal projects) or renaming the file would be the only good solution. In the corporate setting, I have seen the problem return week after week any time anyone along the chain merges a branch in. In other words, you may have to repeatedly continue to remove them over and over again, but as soon as a single person merges, the old problem returns back to step 1 and you start all over